# Why can't I properly parse an Array of Strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

I am having a problem with parsings strings; I can't seem to find out why my String Array's values are not equal to what they should be! This may seem weird, so here is a simplified version of the code (The application is much larger, so I just made a small program to explain my point)

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String src = "beep zap derp flop";
    String delims = "[ ]+";
    String[] tokens = src.split(delims);

    if (tokens[0] == "beep") {
        System.out.println("you said beep!");
    } else {

               for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                    System.err.println("'" + tokens[i] + "'");
               }
          }
     }
}
```

My output is

```
'beep'
'zap'
'derp'
'flop'
```

I know for a fact that tokens[0] is beep, but the Java does not seem to notice. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/758280

Comment: Tags are automatically added to the title as necessary, don’t add them manually.

Comment: @Matisse : since you got 3 answers and all are correct. Accept the one you want. You should accept answered questions.

Comment: @Saher - 99% of the people who ask questions like this will never return to the site once they get their copy/paste answer.  That's why these questions should be downvoted and/or closed... so they don't pollute the site with useless duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

You should never use the `==` operator to compare the contents of `Strings` in Java.  When used with `Objects` such as `Strings`, the `==` operator compares the *references* for equality.  In other words, `==` will only return `true` for objects if both references refer to the same exact object.  If you have two *different* `String` objects, then `==` will return `false` even if the contents are the same.

Use [`String#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) to compare the contents of `Strings`.  This method will compare the contents of the `String` objects character-by-character to determine if the contents are identical.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you so much, you have no idea how much this helped! Now I can finally attempt to make a horribly inefficient scripting language interpreter for my game engine!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.equals` to compare Strings.

The *equals* method checks the actual contents of the strings, the `==` operator checks whether the two objects reference the same instance.

```
String.equals(String other)
```

See this: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2003/04/how_equals_work.html

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you have to use `equals` method to compare two strings. For example, if you want to compare `String a` with `String b`, you can say `if (a.equals(b))`. The `==` operator checks if two strings are references to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

public class Test 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)    {
String src = "beep zap derp flop";
String delims = "[ ]+";
String[] tokens = src.split(delims);

if ("beep".equals(tokens[0]))
{
    System.out.println("you said beep!");
} 
else
{

           for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                System.err.println("'" + tokens[i] + "'");
           }
      }

}
```

}